# Convert Data Pulled from Server To String

Tags: python, string, twitch, chatbot

I have been working on a TwitchTV Python chat bot for a while now, but I'm still getting to grips with Python.

It may seem simple, but this has confused me so I decided I would ask:

I'm currently pulling messages from Twitch Chat using `data = irc.recv`

What I want to do is use the data pulled and turn it into a string, so that I can then check for capitals in the messages using `str.isupper()`

I've already tried a few ways;

```
data = irc.recv (4096)
msg = data()
capsTime = "30s"
str = msg
if str.isupper():
   message("[-] Woah! Hold back on the caps! (Timeout " + capsTime + ")")
   message("/timeout " + user + capsTime)
# variable "user" already defined
```

This is just one, that unfortunately didn't work.

---

EDIT:

This is my new code, It runs without error messages, but It doesn't function as I want it to;

```
while True:
   data = irc.recv (4096)
   user = data.split(':')[1]
   user = user.split('!')[0]
   caps = data.split(':')[0]
   capsmsg = str(data)

   print data
   if data.find('PING') != -1: 
       irc.send('PONG ' + data.split()[1] + '\r\n')

   if capsmsg.isupper():
       message("[-] Woah! Hold back on the caps, " + user + "! (Timeout 30s)")
       message("/timeout " + user + " 30s")
```

---

EDIT 2:

Expected output:
If a message is found in ALL caps, it will print this message and time the user out:
`message("[-] Woah! Hold back on the caps, " + user + "! (Timeout 30s)")`

Current output:
The bot does not pick the message up or run the scripted code.

Comment: "didn't work" - we'll need a bit more info than that. Please add all error messages and unexpected behavior you encountered.

Comment: Did you tried a simple cast like `stri = str(msg)`? I renamed the str variable because it's a non-allowed name.

Comment: str is a reserved keyword!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = irc.recv (4096)
# msg = data()
capsTime = "30s"
mystr = repr(data)
if mystr.isupper():
   message("[-] Woah! Hold back on the caps! (Timeout " + capsTime + ")")
   message("/timeout " + user + capsTime)
# variable "user" already defined
```

Don't use reserved keyword.

Comment: Thanks for this - it didn't quite work, as it gave me this error message though: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` for the line `msg = data()`

I also forgot to mention I am pretty new to Python, so sorry if I seem a stupid being unable to solve this for myself.

Comment: @pythagon  OK, I see your problem. I update my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: Fixed the error of not being able to call the string - error is now 'msg' is not defined.

Comment: @pythagon In this code, there is no msg any more. Did you use msg anywhere else? You can replace msg with data and try again.

Comment: I added the code as you put it. It's giving no errors, but it isn't working when tested in the Twitch chat.
I've updated my original post with my new code below.

Comment: @pythagon What's your expected output? And what's it now? Can you update it in your original post?

Comment: @pythagon capsmsg.isupper()  returns True if all cased characters in capsmsg are uppercase and there is at least one cased character in it. Obviously, in your case, capsmsg.isupper() returns False. You can print it out to check if I'm right.

Comment: Ok thanks. I knew about that, but I'm now trying to get it to return 'True' if the message is in all caps. I'll have a mess about with it, but I will just leave this question here instead of going on. 
Thank you for all of your advice and help!